# Adding Placeholder Text to jQuery Tokenizer

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jQuery Tokenizer (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and am trying to add placeholder text like a normal input would have.

I've tried putting the text in the typical `placeholder` tag element like this:

```
<input data-autocomplete-source="http://localhost:3000/city_to_zips" id="account_town" name="city_to_zip_id" placeholder="Enter city..." type="text" style="display: none; ">
```

but, clearly, the tokenizer is hiding that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:** Quick and dirty way, would be to add the placeholder attribute directly into the input that is created in your [jquery.tokeninput.js](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js) file:

```
// Create a new text input an attach keyup events
var input_box = $("<input type=\"text\"  autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Enter city...\">")
```

**Method 2:** Add placeHolderText as one of the default settings. First add the parameter into the DEFAULT_SETTINGS e.g.:

`placeHolderText: 'Enter City...',`

then add the following:

`.attr("placeholder", $(input).data("settings").placeHolderText)`

before

`.attr("id", $(input).data("settings").idPrefix + input.id)`

By default the placeholder text will be "Enter City...", you can override this when setting up the tokeninput e.g.:

```
$(function() {
    $("#account_town").tokenInput("http://example.com/search", {
    'placeHolderText': 'Enter Town...',
});
```

See [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/k7rnDdvN) (changes are on lines 31, 244)

Comment: I think I get 80% of what you are saying, but I get lost on the "Or you could add placeHolderText..." but.  Could you maybe put a gist up of what you are thinking?

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: How can we remove placeHolderText when at least one item is selected in the box? And put it back when all items have been removed again?